# Cómo puedo mostrar un AlertDialog cada vez que se abre la aplicación [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alertdialog

cómo podría mostrar un AlertDialog cada vez que el usuario abre la aplicación. En este momento se muestra cada que paso de cualquier tab del menú al home, lo único que quiero es que se pueda ejecutar cuando se ejecute la app no cuando el usuario vaya navegando entre tabs del menú[image]

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => checkFirstRun(context));
  }
  Future checkFirstRun(BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstRun = prefs.getBool('isFirstRun') ?? true;

    if (isFirstRun) {
      _showDialog(context);// Whatever you want to do, E.g. Navigator.push()
      prefs.setBool('isFirstRun', false);
    } else {
      _showDialog(context);
    }
  }

void _showDialog(BuildContext context){
    showDialog(
        context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
          return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding:  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            content: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,//300,
                   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,//600,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/img/promo_alert.jpg',
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  trailing: FloatingActionButton(
                    mini: true,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60)
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,), onPressed: ()=> Navigator.of(context).pop())
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
      }
    );
}
```

Llamo a mi función en el initState del Home y lo que quiero es que se limite a que se ejecute una sola vez cada que se abre la app y que no se ejecute cuando vuelva a esa pantalla

Comment: mira este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrBZ7jCbSk

Answer (score 0):

Tiene un error en su logicá. Está mostrando el AlertDialog en su 'if' y 'else':

```
if (isFirstRun) {
      _showDialog(context);
    } else {
      _showDialog(context);
    }
```

Además, si desea mostrar el diálogo cada vez que se abre la aplicación, debe @override didChangeAppLifecycleState()

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print("app is resumed");
        _showDialog(context);
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print("app is inactive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print("app is paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print("app is detached");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Lo intenté pero me sigue mostrando el AlertDialog una vez que se cierra, incluso si vuelvo al home, pero muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que hago es en el `initState` de mi homePage llamar a la función de un `showDialog` para presentar el tutorial de como manejar la aplicación, en este caso esta alerta solo se mostrara 3 veces siempre y cuando e usuario presione en "ver tutorial" u "omitir" cada que el usuario toque omitir o tutorial almaceno un valor en sharedPreferences para asi validar despues las veces:

```
    void initState(){
       mostarCuadroTutorial();
     }
```

aqui el alertDialog:

```
    void mostrarCuadroTutorial() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) async {
      SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final contador = preferences.getInt('contador');
      if (contador == null || contador < 3) {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (builder) {
              return AlertDialog(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  content: SizedBox(
                    width: 400,
                    height: 240,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset('assets/tutorial/alertatuto.jpeg'),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: Container(
                            margin:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, bottom: 50),
                            child: FlatButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                              color: const Color.fromRGBO(82, 120, 187, 10),
                              onPressed: () {
                                pfrc.contadorTapsTuto(3);
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (builder) =>
                                            const Tutorial()));
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                'MIRA EL TUTORIAL',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () async {
                                SharedPreferences preferences =
                                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                final getCount = preferences.getInt('contador');

                                if (getCount == null) {
                                  pfrc.contadorTapsTuto(1);
                                } else {
                                  if (getCount == 1) {
                                    int total = getCount + 1;
                                    pfrc.contadorTapsTuto(total);
                                  }
                                }
                                if (getCount == 2) {
                                  pfrc.contadorTapsTuto(3);
                                }
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: FutureBuilder(
                                  future: pfrc.obtenerContadorTuto(),
                                  builder: (builder, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.data == 2) {
                                      return const Text(
                                        'No ver mas',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                          decorationStyle:
                                              TextDecorationStyle.double,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      return const Text(
                                        'Omitir',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                          decorationStyle:
                                              TextDecorationStyle.double,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                );
            });
      } else if (contador == 3) {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

//-------------ACTUALIZACIÓN----------

Como dijiste en el comentario tu quieres que siempre se muestre la ventana, entonces únicamente hay que ignorar el `SharedPreferences`:

```
void initState(){
       mostarCuadroTutorial();
     }
```

luego:

```
 void mostrarCuadroTutorial(){
   showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (builder) {
          return AlertDialog(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              content: SizedBox(
                width: 400,
                height: 240,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/tutorial/alertatuto.jpeg'),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: Container(
                        margin:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, bottom: 50),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(82, 120, 187, 10),
                          onPressed: () {
          
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'MIRA EL TUTORIAL',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: ()  {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                                    'Cerrar',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      decoration: 
                                   TextDecoration.underline,
                                      decorationStyle:
                                  TextDecorationStyle.double,
                                    ),
                                  );
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        });
```

Comment: Perdón la demora, estaba pensando usar  SharedPreferences para que no muestre, lo que quiero es que el AlertDialog se muestre cada vez que el usuario entra a la app, no importa la cantidad de veces que lo cierre pero que al abrir nuevamente se muestre.

Comment: listo, voy a editar la pregunta ya quitando las partes que no deberías usar y asi te funcionaría

Comment: Ok, lo haré muchas gracias!